# Change default cursor position in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a c# based Winforms Project where I have used a ComboBox filled with some values and Set AutoCompleteMode = Append . Now the problem is whenever I type a alphabet ,the ComboBox show the suggestion but the cursor position is always is at the last . Any suggestion how to change this behaviour .

Comment: Can you be more specific on what kind of problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I found out that the cursor position is always at the last of suggested word whereas i want that it should be at the last of the words that I type